# Sort all Gmail contacts by contact frequency

Tags: gmail, google-contacts

Is it possible to sort **all** Gmail contacts by contact frequency, either directly from Gmail or using a external tool/service? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not in GMail. The only free consumer service with a similar function is [Gist](http://www.gist.com). It allows you to sort contacts by "Importance" (overall frequency & depth of conversations) and by communications sent/received to/from a contact. However, it scans only the last 30 days of communication history for new accounts. Everything else is expensive enterprise customer relationship management software.

Answer (score 0):

You can also have a try at [xobni](http://www.xobni.com/download/gmail).

It had this functionality on Outlook, I do think it will work for Gmail too. And it adds a lot of funny (or useful) features.